# Promise map (node.js) with large list seems to stop iterating after certain index

Tags: node.js, list, promise, bluebird

I'm using the bluebird Promise library. From this library I'm using `Promise.mapSeries()` to perform a mapping operation on a very large list (size=747357).

The code looks as follows (psuedo):

```javascript
function myFunc(data) {
  return Promise.mapSeries(data, handler)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Success!');
      return Promise.resolve(data);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

In the handler, I'm doing a couple of things:

- Running other Promise functions (recursive)
- Returning a new data structure to be stored in the resulting array

In the handler function, I add a `console.log('Iter: ', i);`.

So then this returns the iter # for each item that's been mapped. It slows and eventually stops at #288. Does this reflect some sort of limit I'm hitting?

I don't understand what the problem is - logic says perhaps this list is too large to handle with `Promise.mapSeries`.

Any advice or solutions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

Here's a snippet of the handler function:

```javascript
function handler(v, i, len) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promise
      .then((data) => {
        return recursivePromiseFn(data)
      })
      .then((data) => {
        let _data = transformData(data);
        statusLogger(i);
        resolve(_data);
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: any particular reason you're using `mapSeries` and not `map`?

Comment: Does your `handler` function return a promise that is connected to all the async opeartions in it?

Comment: Ahh good point. @AyushGupta I'm using mapSeries so that I can get access to sequential index information (for progress checking).

Comment: you can get the index in `map` too, as the second parameter of the function passed

Comment: @jfriend00 my `handler` function returns a promise that has a promise.then().then() and has a final Promise.resovle() in the last then... do you think I should have it return a `new Promise()` instead?

Comment: post the code for `handler` if you can

Comment: Is there any benefit of using `.map()` over `.mapSeries()` ?

Comment: @AyushGupta have posted the handler function.

Comment: That snippet of the handler function doesn't show us enough.  You should avoid the promise anti-pattern (wrapping an existing promise in another promise).  Just build off an return the original promise.  Don't wrap it in another one.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. In my recursive function, there is a conditional that seems to be sending the function into an infinite loop. Working through it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with `Promise.map` or `Promise.mapSeries`. The problem was an infinite loop in one of my promise functions. This loop seemed to prevent the promise loop from continuing.

A noteworthy comment was that you should avoid using the Promise anti-pattern. This is true but was not the cause of the problem.